# Django Rest Framework - main url HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I have in my project in the main `urls.py` file the following:

```
# REST Framework packages
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

# ... My viewsets serialized
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet) 
# ... Another viewsets 
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    # Home url in my project        

    url(r'^', include('userprofiles.urls')),
    # Call the userprofiles/urls.py application

    url(r'^pacientes/',  include('userprofiles.urls', namespace='pacientes')),
    # Patients url

    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
    # Rest frameworks urls
]
```

Until here, when I type in my browser calling to my local server `http://localhost:8000/api/` I get this like response:

```
[08/Dec/2016 16:39:42] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7084
```

And my REST `url's` serialized models appear

After, I've created one url additional in the `userprofiles/urls.py` application with some regular expression of this way:

```
from .views import PatientDetail
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', PatientDetail.as_view(), name='patient_detail'),

]
```

And, when I go to `http://localhost:8000/api/` I get this response:

```
Not Found: /api/
[08/Dec/2016 16:42:26] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1753
```

My rest frameworks url is not found and in my browser, denote that the url   which call to PatientDetailView is the origin of this problem:

[image]

My PatientDetailView have the following:

```
class PatientDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = PatientProfile
    template_name = 'patient_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'patientdetail'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super(PatientDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # And other actions and validations here in forward ...
```

In my regular expressions defined in `userprofiles/urls.py` I am doing:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', PatientDetail.as_view(), name='patient_detail')
```

The model PatientProfile have a slug field (username of patient). I pass this slug in the url.

In addition I want that allow me alphanumerics characters upper and lowercase with the `[\w\-]` parameter, and allow underscores and hyphen characters and many times.

Is possible that my regular expression may be the origin of the problem?
What can be happened in relation to my `/api` django-restframework url be not found?

Answer (score 1):

`api` is full match for regular expression `[\w\-]+` using in 'userprofiles.urls'. So when you type `http://localhost:8000/api/` Django returns first found urlpattern which is `url(r'^', include('userprofiles.urls'))`. Try to swap lines:

```
url(r'^pacientes/',  include('userprofiles.urls', namespace='pacientes')),
# Patients url
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
url(r'^', include('userprofiles.urls')),
```

Answer (score 1):

The order in which you define your URLs matter. Django tries to match your URL against every pattern until one of them matches.

Note that you included this line:

```
url(r'^', include('userprofiles.urls')),
```

before:

```
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
```

which wasn't a problem because the first pattern to match was the latter.

However, when you added the `PatientDetail` view URL pattern:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', PatientDetail.as_view(), name='patient_detail')
```

`/api/` was a match. Thus, the `PatientDetail` view was called and your 404 error happened because *no patient was found with username **api***, not because the URL was not found.